# Three riddles in one

Tags: word, wordplay, rebus

Look at the conversation below

> Mary: Oh no! My ___________! 
>   John: _________ happened? 
>   Mary: I don't know! 
>   John: You're REACTing too much, EH?

Clue 1: 
The answer is three words, but if you join the first two words together, I shouldn't write it out. You only fix the third word when it is in that state.

Clue two: 
[image]

Find the two blanks and a word, all the clues given above.

Hint 1:

> I have to give credit to some of my friends for making one of the riddles. The other day, one of them ran up to me and asked me to say __________ really fast and when I said it, I realised that I said something really wrong

Hint 2:

> Anagram

Hint 3:

> Something related to school

Hint 4:

> When I give out the hints, it only refers to *ONE* of the words. They are not hints to *all* the words

Hint 5:

> One of them is more of a synonym of another word; you need it to know the synonym

Hint 6:

> _______ (preposition) the _________?!!!

Hint 7: (The biggest giveaway)

> Hint 1 refers to blank one,  hint two is the word, hint three is blank one and hint five is blank two

Hint 8:

> To clear the confusion: the first blank is three words

Hint 9:

> Blank one is three words; blank two is four; the word is either of the two anagrams

Hint 10:

> Since the first blank is made of three words, the first two words joined together is something that is pretty inappropriate... it's the thing...

Hint 11:

> The first word of the first blank is a stationery

Comment: Does this have anything to do with rot13(fbsn xvat)?

Comment: @VirtualValentin Nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first blank:

> My PEN IS BROKEN. PEN/IS being a little too risque to write out. *Broken* being something needing to be fixed when it is in this state

The second blank

> What in the world. A rebus

The anagram

> Either Teacher or Cheater, coming from REACT and EH

Comment: Good job! Finally solved it!

Answer (score 1):

**Partial**

Clue two appears to be

> What on earth?

For the conversation, John's missing part

> can only be "what" , or possibly "what on earth"

and his last line

> REACT and EH are an anagram of CHEATER or TEACHER, either of which would match hints 2 and 3. Or possibly EARTH, with a C and E left over.

But I'm not sure how this ties together.

Answer (score 1):

New Answer

> **WORLD WATER ACT** or Water for the World Act

Because

> Hint 6 and Clue 2 - What In The World
>  Mary: Oh no! My __ **HEART** __ ! - anagram - EARTH - synonym - WORLD
>  EDIT: or - 
>  Mary: Oh no! My __ **WORLD** __ ! 
>  John: __ **WHAT** __ happened?
>  Mary: I don't know!
>  John: You're **RE** - **ACT**ing too much, EH?
>  Or - WORLD WATER ACT
>  **Note: This feels a bit stretchy, and doesn't quite match the anagram hint. So, feel free to build off of this if it makes sense.**
>  From the Web - The Water for the World Act of 2014 will help address the needs of over one-third of world's total population who lack access to basic sanitation or clean water. In 2005, the Water for the Poor Act was signed into law, making water, sanitation, and hygiene (WASH) a U.S. foreign policy priority.

Previous

> Mary: Oh no! My __ **HEART** __ ! - anagram - EARTH?
>  John: __ **WHAT** __ happened? - anagram - THAW?
>  Mary: I don't know!
>  John: You're **REACT**ing too much, **EH**? - anagram - TEACHER or CHEATER (credit to Mohirl)

Comment: @UnidentifiedX, rot13(Fb onfrq ba uvag sbhe, uvag bar bayl eryngrf gb bar bs gur zvffvat jbeqf?)

Comment: Yep, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:
For the second clue,

> I believe that the phrase is "What in the world" instead of "What on Earth". This is also a logical explanation to the rebus, as the WHAT is surrounded INside the Earth, which we call "WORLD" a lot of times(e.g. World wide web, Wikipedia is the world's largest encyclopedia)

Some thought(s):

> The first two words might be TEACH and a word starting with ER.

Comment: Oooo.. somone's got one of em'....

Answer (score 1):

I think the first blank is

> PEN IS GONE, because the first word is a stationery item and the combination of the first two words matches your ‘dirty’ clues.

The second blank is

> WHAT IN THE WORLD, because the rebus shows the word “what” in the middle of the earth, and world is a synonym for earth. It is also of the form ____ preposition the ____.

Then the word is

> Either TEACHER or CHEATER, being the two anagrams of “REACT EH”.

Not sure if any of this is correct....

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a stretch, but given that ...

- Clue 1 talks about "joining the first two words together" so as not to "write out", and the third word needing to be "fixed".
- Clue 2 is of course the phrase "what on (the) earth", which Hint 6 also seems to refer to.
- Hints 2, 3, and 4 suggest that

  > one of the three words involves anagrams and is related to school.
- Hints 1 and 5 suggest that

  > there may be some odd pronunciation of words involved, and also some synonyms.

... I wonder if **the answer** is something like

> TEA + CHER(?) = TEACHER.

The conversation would then be:

> Mary: Oh no! My TEA!
>  John: 'CHER(?) happened?
>  Mary: I don't know!
>  John: You're REACTing too much, EH?

This fits with most of the clues and hints given:

> after joining the first two words together, there is no need to write out the third one, but it can be found from REACT+EH after anagramming. That third word is related to school. The link I'm missing is how to get from "what on earth" to "cher", and given Hints 1 and 5 I'm wondering if this may involve some unusual synonym or accent, possibly a regionalism.

Comment: Good try, however, that is not the intended answer.